# How to rename ec2-instance name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to rename 100 ec2 instances using cli how to do that ?

This will show all instance names :

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:productionpriority,Values=productionpriority" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[ [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0],PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress, InstanceId, InstanceType, Placement.AvailabilityZone]'
```

But how to modify Instance name ie replace old name with new one ?

Comment: Get a list of instance ids and then use "delete-tag" on name, followed by "create-tag" on name for each instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ec2-create-tags  i-xxxx --tag "Name=PROD-DEL-xxx"
```

Comment: As of April '18, the following command worked for me: 
`aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-xxx --tag "Key=Name,Value=PROD-DEL-xxx"`